# Check multiple checkboxes in knockout.js binded by JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I'm new to JSON and knockout. I'm facing an issue which is that I have a dataset in JSON with for instance 10 booleans defined e.g.

```
IsHappy = true;
IsSad = false;
IsAngry = true;
```

etc. My ViewModel is created from the JSON string, and I bind values to the checkbox as such :-

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsHappy"/>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSad"/>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsAngry"/>
```

I convert the ViewModel back to JSON and ajax it to save to server.

This all works fine however I cannot figure out how to implement a 'select all' feature. I've read through the examples online (http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/eT7xV/) which involves creating an observableArray and toggling the IsSelected() observable, but in my case how do I map different JSON attributes to the IsSelected() attribute, and likewise how does toggling the IsSelected() observable update the original JSON attribute.

I tried just setting the attr('checked') using jquery but doing so checks the box but does not update the ViewModel, which means when I converted it back to JSON and posted it to server side no changes were detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an array of your property names (you can explicitly list them or you can collect them using Object.keys).

Then when your `allSelected` checkbook is checked you go through these array of property names and set them according to the `newValue`:

```
viewModel.allSelected.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    var _this = this;

    //var checkboexes = ['IsHappy', 'IsSad', 'IsAngry'];
    var checkboexes = Object.keys(_this).filter(function(k) { 
       return k.indexOf('Is') == 0; 
    });

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(checkboexes, function(banner) {        
       _this[banner](newValue); 
    });
}, viewModel);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WdqM3/).

Comment: I'm both shocked and amazed by how fast you generated the JSFiddle with the solution ...!!!

Comment: as a follow up, is there any way to reset the values back to the original (true, false, true) ?

Comment: There is no easy way to restore the previous values. You have to store the values temporary somewhere or retreive them again from the server. There are some plugins/pattern doing this: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html